# still resonates with delight at the marvels of creation

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the bold part mean?

> Haeckel’s fabulously illustrated book Art Forms in Nature **still
>   resonates with delight at the marvels of creation**.

[Art and Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=5_jVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&lpg=PT32&dq=Haeckel%E2%80%99s%20fabulously%20illustrated%20book%20Art%20Forms%20in%20Nature%20still%20resonates%20with%20delight%20at%20the%20marvels%20of%20creation.&source=bl&ots=X9EfG2SICW&sig=ulis4gDo_ptKmksp6fmI8Xhpc44&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMI1ZGb9t_dxgIVQVyICh00tAvu#v=onepage&q=Haeckel%E2%80%99s%20fabulously%20illustrated%20book%20Art%20Forms%20in%20Nature%20still%20resonates%20with%20delight%20at%20the%20marvels%20of%20creation.&f=false), by Sîan Ede

Answer (score 4):

Roughly, this means the book is still showing its extreme appreciation of the wonders of nature.

The book is being personified here as having delight and wonderment. The use of 'still' implies it hasn't lost any potency with age.